# Unmarshal YAML returns incomplete result

Tags: go, yaml

Input Yaml:

```
params: 
  - aws.region: ["us-west-1","us-west-2"]
  - aws.s3path: ["s3-path-1", "s3-path-2"]
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {  
    var f File
    wfyaml, _ := os.Open("temp.yaml")
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(wfyaml)
    yaml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &f)
    fmt.Print(f)
}

type File struct {
    Params Params `yaml:"params"`
}

type Params []struct { // <<< This [] behavior is confusing
    AwsRegion []string `yaml:"aws.region"`
    S3path    []string `yaml:"aws.s3path"`
}
```

Output:

```
{[{[us-west-1 us-west-2] []} {[] [s3-path-1 s3-path-2]}]}%
```

If I use

```
type Params struct { // <<< This [] behavior is confusing
        AwsRegion []string `yaml:"aws.region"`
        S3path    []string `yaml:"aws.s3path"`
    }
```

Then output is `{{[] []}}%`

I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? Is the YAML input rigid i.e. you can't change its format? Or you want the item slice lists in one single struct - rather than a slice of structs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `params` from your input yaml is an array.

If you change your input yaml to the following, then you will find your code with `type Params struct` works as you would expect, because `params` is no longer an array in this case.

```
params:
    aws.region: ["us-west-1","us-west-2"]
    aws.s3path: ["s3-path-1", "s3-path-2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is consistent with the YAML input:

```
params: 
  - aws.region: ["us-west-1","us-west-2"]
  - aws.s3path: ["s3-path-1", "s3-path-2"]
```

Above, `params` is an array, because its elements start with a `-`. Each `-` is an array element, and since each element has a key, `param` is an array of objects. The first element is an object with key `aws.region`, and the second element is an object with key `aws.s3path`. These objects are themselves string arrays.